# Laravel sum values of serialized data

Tags: php, laravel

I have serialized data stored in database and i need to calculate some of their values such as `weight`, `total quantity` or `total price` etc. (**but for now i only need to get total weight**)

## Samples

Here is how data in database looks like:

```
"a:5:{s:4:\"name\";s:11:\"Product One\";s:5:\"price\";s:5:\"15000\";s:8:\"quantity\";i:3;s:10:\"attributes\";a:1:{s:4:\"attr\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:6:\"weight\";s:5:\"value\";s:2:\"35\";}}s:10:\"conditions\";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:3:\"red\";s:5:\"value\";i:0;}i:1;a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:1:\"L\";s:5:\"value\";i:0;}}}"

"a:5:{s:4:\"name\";s:11:\"Product Two\";s:5:\"price\";s:6:\"436436\";s:8:\"quantity\";i:1;s:10:\"attributes\";a:1:{s:4:\"attr\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:6:\"weight\";s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";}}s:10:\"conditions\";a:0:{}}"
```

> #### Update
>
> **To make it more clear here is how sample codes above look like in network tab.**

[image: three]

> Based on this i should get totalWeight of 36 KG

## Code

Here is how I currently returning data to my component from controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->user();
    $items2 = CartStorage::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

    $items = [];
    foreach($items2 as $item){
        $items[] = unserialize($item['cart_data']);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $items,
        'success' => 'Your cart items retrieved successfully.'
    ], 200);
}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: one]

**Just in case you need to see database structure**

[image: two]

## Question

**How can I sum the weight of my cart products?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Final code

```
    $items2 = CartStorage::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();

    $totalWeight = 0;
    foreach ($items2 as $subArray) {
        if(isset($subArray['cart_data'])){
            $ans = json_decode($subArray['cart_data'],true);
            if(is_array($ans)){
                foreach($ans['attributes'] as $attribute) {
                    $totalWeight += $attribute['value']; 
                }
            }
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Laravel collection aggregation function.

```
CartStorage::where('user_id', $user->id)->get()-sum('qty');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sum

Comment: first of all i want sum the wight which is under attributes array, second i need my weight sum as separate variable that case i would have `$items` as well as `$totalWeight` so my return part sends 2 variables